# magento 1.9 going very slow after create new category

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, slowdown

I have created a new category on my store after creating this website taking 15-20 seconds to load, but before that it's taking only 5-6 seconds

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: @KayMarker00 slow speed issue arises after creating new category why this issue arises by creating only one category that's my question..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Please re-index all the index and if it is still slow you can try by using flat tables for catalog.
Also make sure you have not added anything wrong in category details like special characters in desc etc.

Comment: @Smith,query issue : SELECT `main_table`.`entity_id`, main_table.`name`, main_table.`path`, `main_table`.`is_active`, `main_table`.`is_anchor`, `url_rewrite`.`request_path` FROM `catalog_category_flat_store_1` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `core_url_rewrite` AS `url_rewrite` ON url_rewrite.category_id=main_table.entity_id AND url_rewrite.is_system=1 AND url_rewrite.store_id = 1 AND url_rewrite.id_path LIKE 'category/%' WHERE (main_table.include_in_menu = '1') AND (main_table.is_active = '1') AND (main_table.path like '1/2/%') ORDER BY `main_table`.`position` ASC    this query is very slow .

Comment: @smith. done changes as suggested on github: https://gist.github.com/SchumacherFM/33eca691e062c06b846e ... resolve issue, is it ok to do?

Comment: @shyopat if issue is resolved using the solution suggested above then its OK,but best practice is to check for module causing the issue also you can check by truncating the core_url_rewrite ttable and reindex the data.

Comment: @shyopat please make sure that apache rewrite module is enabled on your server if rewrite is enabled from magento.

Comment: Thanks Smith.. issue resolved using above method. tried all other methods but not working